# Having a word + whitespace as delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to split the string "`HI. HOW ARE YOU? I AM FINE!`" into a string array using split function with the following syntax

```
String[] i = "HI. HOW ARE YOU? I AM FINE! ".split("[\\. |? |! ]+");
```

Expected output

> HI
>
> HOW ARE YOU
>
> I AM FINE

But in intellij, it's saying "Duplicate character literal" and it's considering space as a separate delimiter.

How do I make sure that it take the full stop plus space, question mark plus space and exclamation plus space without it considering space as a separate delimiter?
Which would be the correct regex for it?
If it can be done without regex, even that is okay.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Try [`String pat = "[.?!]+\\s*";`](https://regex101.com/r/8TI6Ax/1)

Comment: What if you have `"HI... HOW ARE YOU??? I AM FINE!!! "`?

Answer (score -1):

A better pattern would be

```
"[?!.]\\s*"
```

As for the error you are getting, that is because the `|` operator does not work within a character class. If you want your pattern to work, change the square brackets `[...]` to parentheses `(...)`.